# mhchem vs expl3 bug

Tags: expl3, mhchem

Does anybody know how to fix this problem with `mhchem` package?

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool
```

Recently I've found this part of `mhchem.sty` code:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_escapeFromTextToItalicMath:n #1
  {
    \ensuremath
      {
        \mhchem@hook@beforeItalicMath
        \bool_if:NT \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool
          {
            \medmuskip=0mu
            \thinmuskip=0mu
            \thickmuskip=0mu
          }
        #1
      }
  }
```

It seems to me problem is connected with `\bool_if:NT \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool` condition which can be wrong with newest `expl3` package. The same bug has successfully been solved in `siunitx` package.

Win 10, MikTeX 2.9.6236, up-to-date

Comment: https://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A2=latex-l;3fb6e8f0.1707

Comment: The siunitx problem has been solved because I notified the author: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/311. So if you want to get a fix for mhchem: write to the author.

Comment: Thank you. I sent him an e-mail  with link to forum's question. Seems simple replacement bool<-bool_lazy can't solve this :)

Comment: Temporary, I make this: `code` \bool_new:N \l__mhchem_cg_isScript
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_escapeFromTextToItalicMath:n #1
  {
    \ensuremath
      {
        \mhchem@hook@beforeItalicMath
        \bool_lazy_any:nT \l__mhchem_cg_isScript
          {
            \medmuskip=0mu
            \thinmuskip=0mu
            \thickmuskip=0mu
          }
        #1
      }
  }

Comment: The problem is that the boolean is *not* defined. Probably in the past an undefined boolean was considered false. This is quite likely a left-over from some older version. By the way, setting `\thinmuskip` to zero is wrong.

Comment: The `\bool_if:NT` code was added in version 4.04, but not accompanied by a definition of the boolean variable, nor with any way to toggle it. Hence it is completely useless.

Comment: @egreg, the code `\thinmuskip=0mu` is not mine, but your suggestion about declaration is right.  I've made it like `\bool_new:N \l__mhchem_cg_isScript`

Comment: Can you add an example of code triggering the bug, please?

Comment: @Alexey: your last comment should have `\bool_new:N \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code `\bool_if:NT \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool {...}` was added in version 4.04 of `mhchem.sty`. However, the addressed boolean variable is nowhere defined.

With previous versions of `expl3`, such a case was dealt with by considering the boolean as false, now it is not so any longer.

By the way, as there obviously is no way to toggle the boolean's value, the code is completely useless (and it would be so even if the boolean was defined).

Here's a temporary fix, which wouldn't be invalid even after the package author defines the boolean variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_if_exist:NF \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool
 {
  \bool_new:N \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\ce{NO_$x$}$

$\ce{NO_$x+y$}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`mhchem` v4.07 fixes this bug.

Thanks a lot for reporting this and all your research into that matter. Thanks @egreg! This seems indeed to be a leftover of an experiment I did once and did not completely reverse. And my (wrong) code stopped working with an `expl3` update. I will publish an update of `mhchem` during the next couple of days.

Comment: Please do not add thank you as answer. Once the update is published you can post an answer showing how it works with the updated version.

Comment: @TeXnician This is no thank you answer. It is an "I noticed this and I am working on an update". Am I not allowed to say thank you on the way? --> meta

Comment: Well, it is. The appropriate answer would be: "It's fixed in version X (problem was...) and this is how it works..." The rest is commentary.

Comment: You can use comments if you need to say thank you not only using the up-vote button.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it directly in mhchem.sty:

```
\bool_new:nT \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mhchem_output_escapeFromTextToItalicMath:n #1
  {
    \ensuremath
      {
        \mhchem@hook@beforeItalicMath
        \bool_lazy_any:nT \l__mhchem_cg_isScript_bool
          {
            \medmuskip=0mu
            \thinmuskip=0mu
            \thickmuskip=0mu
          }
        #1
      }
  }
```

Comment: The name of a boolean variable should end with `_bool`. Besides, changing package code is not the best way to solve such issues. On another machine the document would choke again.

Comment: @egreg, Ok. Also, I'm glad to see the author of this package here.