# Why is it wrong to set \medmuskip or \thinskip temporarily to zero?

Tags: spacing

I was [told](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382991/mhchem-vs-expl3-bug/383023#comment947705_382991)

> setting \thinmuskip to zero is wrong.

Why is that so?

I am deliberately asking this generically, because the statement was so generic.

---

I used this method to enhance the typography of things like `$A + (2n+1)B$` where I feel, the spacing around the 2nd `+` should be smaller than around the first one (Gestalt law of proximity).

[image]
[image]

Comment: No the spacing around the 2nd `+` should not be smaller: “Make similar things similar and equal things equal.”

Comment: The title and the contents don't match. I talked about `\thinmuskip`, not `\medmuskip`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke With your approach, Donald Knuth would have been wrong by changing font size and spacings in subscripts.

Comment: @egreg I set all 3 skips to 0 and I thought your remark was not limited to thin, but meant all of them.

Comment: @mhchem I'd have referred to all three of them, not specifically to `\thinmuskip`.

Comment: @mchem: You are comparing apples and pears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion here.

TeX uses `\medmuskip` around binary operation symbols; whether the space around the two + signs in `A+(2n+1)B` should be the same or different is a stylistic question. In my opinion the spaces should be the same.

TeX uses `\thinmuskip` in various places, most importantly at the sides of an *operator* under certain circumstances. An example is worth several words in order to show it should *never* be set to zero:

```
$2\sin x$

\thinmuskip=0mu

$2\sin x$

\bye
```

Compile with `pdftex`.

[image]

Is this enough of a reason?

---

About `\medmuskip`, here is a comparison:

```
$A+(2n+1)B$

$A+\hbox{\medmuskip=0mu$(2n+1)$}B$

\bye
```

[image]

Note that TeX won't use the spacings related to `\medmuskip` or `\thickmuskip` in subscripts or superscripts, but will still insert those related to `\thinmuskip`.

Comment: In chemistry, there is no `\sin` or similar, just `+` or `-`. So I should be safe. However, I found that one instance that I used because math inside `\text` looses the information that it is inside a subscript `$X_{a+b,\text{\ensuremath{a+b}}}$`. I'd be glad if that could be solved otherwise. Should I raise a new question?

Comment: @mhchem `\newif\ifinsubscript` then `... $X_{\insubscripttrue a+b, \text{\ensuremath{\ifinsubscript\scriptstyle\fi a+b}}}$`. Is that enough? Of course you can automate, or create symbolic names, but the idea is mostly that. (I don't remember if `\..true` were global assignments, in that case, add `\insubscriptfalse` at the end of the subscript.

Comment: @mhchem Yes, `\text` in some sense loses the information, but it can be fixed. I seem to remember something of this kind. A new question with details seems the most suitable strategy.

Comment: --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383156/73371