# Chemmacros: Undefined control sequence. \end

Tags: environments, chemistry, chemmacros

When I try to create a reaction from chemmacros/reactions I got the following error. I dunno what I am missing. Please help. Thank you.

> line 11: Undefined control sequence. \end
>   line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. \end
>   line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. \end

Minimum Working Example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions}}
\begin{document}
\begin{reaction}
    A + B -> C
\end{reaction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably related issue raised on Github: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/10

Comment: The boolean `\l__chemmacros_hyperref_bool` is not properly defined. Until the package is updated you can add a definition for it like in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383007/2388

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in v5.8b (2017/08/28), the new version is on its way to CTAN and will reach the major distributions soon.