# Chemmacros reactions environment compile error

Tags: chemmacros

The package `chemmacros` will throw the following error when I try to use the `reaction` or `reactions` environments. It does not happen when I use the starred variants. I am using MacTeX-2017 and am (fairly) confident everything is up to date.

```
./main.tex:11: Undefined 

control sequence.
<argument> \l__chemmacros_hyperref_bool 

l.11     \end
             {reaction}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

MWE. I compile with latexmk on Atom but the same error occurs in TeXShop and using pdfLatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[compatibility = 5.8a]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules=reactions,
}

\begin{document}
Before
    \begin{reaction}
        H2O -> CO2
    \end{reaction}
Afterwards
\end{document}
```

I also noticed that a pdf file is made, and everything seems to be in there. However, there is a Greek letter after the equation number that the chemmacros package does not indicate should be there (p43).[image]

Comment: Issue already raised: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383332/117534

Comment: Workaround: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383007/2388.

Comment: @Troy I don't know how I missed that -- maybe becuase it is very general and doesn't mention the reaction module in the title at all? I may have seen `\end` in it and thought "nope. not my issue."

Comment: @BenjaminGray No worries, my comment also serves the purpose of informing others who stumble across your question to check out related questions (which may have phrased the question differently, as you rightly pointed out). It's also a sign that I've spent too much time here `:p`

Comment: @Troy Thanks for understanding, I was a bit annoyed that this issue already existed, and I was unable to find it when doing research. When I Google search "chemmacros reaction error" the first result is some issue opened Oct. 2015, followed by my question here, followed by unrelated stuff. The question you linked to doesn't even appear on (at least) pages 1-3.

Comment: Any solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @Viridjan Issue is raised here https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/10

Comment: Some way to bypass this error? Something like restoring old packages until the new will be ok?